# Quality factor of earth's rotation around sun

Tags: orbital-motion, resonance

I am taking a course on the resonance phenomena, and the professor was mentioning something like, the earth's rotation around the sun has a quality factor of $10^7$. Does it mean, after $10^7$ years, the earth's rotation will be damped?